# How to change the speed on send keys sSlenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I can't seem to find anywhere how to change how quickly Selenium types keys into a box. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Do you want a small delay between each key press?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to do this:

```
import time

def slow_send_keys(elem, keys, delay=0.1):
    for k in keys:
        elem.send_keys(k)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Then use it like so:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
slow_send_keys(elem, 'Tron')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think we need some clarification. If you are using SendKeys to send to a webpage, you should be able to send them as fast as possible, so long as the place you're sending them to exists. If the page loads in parts, you can use lines like:

```
Set element = sel.FindElementById("Main_btnNext", timeout:=10000)
```

This will look for an element in the HTML with an Id of "Main_btnNext" and will wait for ten seconds until it appears.
If you want to send only one letter at a time, you could repeat the SendKey for each character in your string, with a pause between each letter.

```
sel.FindElementById("Main_txtPassword", -1, True).SendKeys ("S")
Set element = sel.FindElementById("elementthatdoesnotexist", timeout:=1000)
sel.FindElementById("Main_txtPassword", -1, True).SendKeys ("t")
Set element = sel.FindElementById("elementthatdoesnotexist", timeout:=1000)
sel.FindElementById("Main_txtPassword", -1, True).SendKeys ("ring")
```

Comment: I am sending them to a webpage however I do not want to send them as fast as possible for some expermination purposes I am simply sending keys to a box with an ID

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, would I have to send each letter differently to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think sending each key one at a time is the most reasonable solution, and that matches Alex Hall's response as well. In his post, he is sending each letter one at a time using a loop.